# Intellij IDEA 2018.3 ultimate edition: What is the hotkey for "Navigate to Injection Point"?

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

As mentioned above I sometimes would like to quickly navigate to the only one injection point of a bean with a combination of some keys. I wathced through the keymap but didn't find anything. Is this kind of shortcut missing in the version I use?

P.S. Build number could maybe be interesting:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.4284.148, built on November 21, 2018
```

Comment: Please try "Navigate | Related Symbol..."

Comment: @y.bedrov It brings me to the unit test class as if I had pressed Ctrl+Shift+T

Comment: Doesn't a straightforward `Ctrl + B` work in this case? If not, please post a reproducible example (probably with screenshots).

Comment: @DmitriyPopov You're a lifesaver! I'm wondering why didn't I get to this on myself. I use `Ctrl+b` daily and dozens of times ^^